# Are PHP Arrays Consecutive Pieces of Memory?

Tags: java, php, arrays, memory

Here's an array in Java:

```
int[] myArray = new int[3];
myArray[0] = 0;
myArray[1] = 1;
myArray[2] = 2;
```

The first line immediately reserves 3 consecutive blocks of memory. Creating a fourth element would actually require creating a new array with int[4], and then transferring values from index 0 to 2 into the new array. Such as the following:

```
int[] mySecondArray = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i += 1) {
    mySecondArray[i] = myArray[i];
}
mySecondArray[3] = 3;
```

But in PHP, we can declare an array, and simply add another element without all the fuss that a Java requires.

```
$my_array = array(0, 1, 2);
$my_array[] = 4;
```

Does PHP actually take care of creating a new array after pushing an additional element onto an existing array? Or are PHP arrays actually not the same (in terms of memory) as arrays in languages such as C and Java? I'm a little concerned, because I see a lot of PHP code that iterates through a loop and appends 50+ new elements onto an existing array, which would be utterly ridiculous to do in Java.

Comment: are you having memory issues?

Comment: I don't know specifics, but I'm sure that the creators of PHP try to handle this as efficiently as possible. PHP arrays encompass a wider variety of data structures than traditional arrays. Such structures certainly exist in C and Java (`ArrayList` comes to mind).

Comment: @Dagon I'm just an intern, but I overhead the developers in the team that I work in argue about which is faster in PHP: 10,000 variable assignments or 10,000 assignments onto a PHP array. This question sort of came up to my mind when they were having their discussion.

Comment: work arguments are some what outside the scope of stack overflow.

Comment: @Dagon You're wrong. This is not outside the scope of stack overflow. I asked a legitimate question about programming that could help others who would like to know how memory works with PHP.

Comment: Side Note:  use System.arraycopy instead of looping.  It's a native method, and you'll get better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or are PHP arrays actually not the same (in terms of memory) as arrays in languages such as C and Java?

In PHP arrays are in fact hash tables. However, the memory management is hardly comparable, because they are two completely different languages.

Comment: I was commenting your initial post and forgot what it read. But I basically thought you said that PHP arrays are like Java or C arrays. I might have misunderstood and that original post is long gone so never mind

Comment: @Esailija Added the original quote again. It should be read like "Yes, it is _not_ like arrays in C and Java". Seems, we are talking about the same.